# How to change image's alpha value without completely reloading every pixel each frame/ OPTIMIZATION

Tags: c++, image, optimization, pixel, sfml

so I'm trying to bring an image to visibility in sfml 1.6 by changing it's alpha value every frame. unfortunately there isn't an overall alpha value for the image, so i have to go through each pixel, one by one and change it's alpha value.

This is extremely slow however, so I wondering **how I could possibly optimize my simple code, or if there was another sfml specific way to handle this.**

anyway here's the code:

Each new frame I Recolor a sprite with a added alpha value of 1.7.

```
// @Return Ptr: a pointer to the stack allocated image so the 
//              user can deallocate it later
sf::Image* RecolorSprite(sf::Sprite& sprite, sf::Color filter, bool subtract){
    // the image has to survive so it's put ont he stack
    sf::Image* image = new sf::Image;
    *image = *sprite.GetImage();

    RecolorImage(*image, filter, subtract);
    sprite.SetImage(*image);

    return image;
}

void RecolorImage(sf::Image& image, sf::Color filter, bool subtract){
    for( int x= 0; x< image.GetWidth(); x++){
        for(int y= 0; y< image.GetHeight(); y++){
            if(subtract){
                sf::Color pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                SubtractColor(pixel, filter);
                image.SetPixel(x, y, pixel);
            }
            else
                image.SetPixel(x, y, image.GetPixel(x, y) + filter);
        }
    }
}

// int used to stop illegal operations on unsigned chars 
void SubtractColor(sf::Color& col1, sf::Color& col2){
    int diff = ((int)col1.r) - ((int)col2.r);
        if(diff >= 0)
            col1.r -= col2.r;
        else
            col1.r = 0;

    diff = ((int)col1.g) - ((int)col2.g);
        if(diff >= 0)
            col1.g -= col2.g;
        else
            col1.g = 0;

    diff = ((int)col1.b) - ((int)col2.b);
        if(diff >= 0)
            col1.b -= col2.b;
        else
            col1.b = 0;

    diff = ((int)col1.a) - ((int)col2.a);
        if(diff >= 0)
            col1.a -= col2.a;
        else
            col1.a = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not pre-create the sprites with all the varying color/alphas. A sprite of sprites. That way you just have to use the correct sprite instead of recalculating the image during run-time. You'll use more space loading all the sprite transitions at the beginning but it will be much faster during the render loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you should be able to use [sf::Drawable::SetColor](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Drawable.php#a8cae9f22220985e368a1b38af7644ffb) for this, giving white as the argument but with a differing alpha value. For instance, to set `sprite`'s alpha to 50%, you could do the following:

```
sprite.SetColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 128));
```

Comment: does the argument color have to be all white?  i've been doing (0,0,0,alpha), so that might explain the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes, the colour should be white. SetColor results in a multiplicative blend with the colours of the pixels in your Sprite's Image. For instance, if you SetColor to (255, 0, 0), that means the pixels in your sprite will retain 100% of their R components, but 0% of their G and B components. If it's set to (0, 0, 0), as you were doing, the resulting image will have 0% R, 0% G, and 0% B, meaning it'll always be black. Hope that clears it up a bit!